# Get latitude and longitude values from MapBox MBTiles

Tags: ios7, maps, latitude-longitude, mapbox

I am new to MapBox and using it for offline maps. How i can get latitude and longitude values  when i tap on MapBox MBTiles. MBTiles has world map along with country names. Also can i get current location using MBTiles with GPS chip on and WiFi/3G off with MapBox? Any suggestion or source code regarding this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you want is `-[RMMapViewDelegate singleTapOnMap:]`.

Comment: Can i adjust RMMarker to user's current location using MBTiles without tapping on map? Is there any method or API to achieve this in mapbox without WiFi/3G? I just wanted to move RMMarker along with user just like in google maps.